# iOS make phone call

Tags: ios, jailbreak, core-telephony

I am able to make a phone call by using `void CTCallDialWithID(NSString *numberToDial);` but my goal is to not have any ui visible and somehow hide the call ui screen.
Any ideas how this could be achieved?

This should work on *Jailbreak devices*!(I am not targeting non *jailbreak devices*)

Comment: Do you still need an answer here?

Comment: I could use an answer here in a serious way...