# iOS Private API Method for Placing a Call Without Displaying the MobilePhone App?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

I know that I can place a call using CoreTelephony's CTCallDialWithID.  I also know that I can hang up with CTCallDisconnect.  I am wondering how I can possibly initiate a call and then hang it up without displaying the MobilePhone app.  I suspect it can be done, but I'm really stretched thin on this one because I'm not seeing anything obvious in either CoreTelephony or the MobilePhone app's headers.

[Creker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2363866/creker) makes me believe it's possible in this unanswered [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441353/ios-make-phone-call) from last year, but I have not been able to find anything resembling help on the subject, so I am turning to you.  I am currently targeting iOS 8.1, but code to accomplish it for any iOS SDK would be of tremendous help to me.

Thanks!

Comment: On iOS 8 you don't actually see MobilePhone app when phone call is displayed - it's actually `InCallService.app`. Here is my answer to the question for iOS 7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729003/hide-a-phone-call-completely-in-ios-jailbreak-device/22897769#22897769 I did port it on iOS 8 but don't feel like posting it for now. Many things can be taken straight from iOS 7 implementation but it needs tweaking to get it to work on iOS 8.

Comment: You're freaking brilliant.  Did you know that?  I'm going to delete this question unless you'd like to preserve the link to the appropriate answer.  Flagged as a duplicate for now, anyway.

Comment: I'll flag it as duplicate anyway. You can delete it or wait for it to be closed as duplicate thus preserving the link to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

see [CTCall](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CTCall)

To initiate a call without using MobilePhone, you can use the **CTCallDial** function.

```
CFStringRef number = CFSTR("15555555555");

CTCallRef call = CTCallDial(number);

/* Hold call */
CTCallHold(call);

/* Resume call */
CTCallResume(call);

/* End call */
CTCallDisconnect(call);
```

> **Note** : The phone number passed to CTCallDial must be normalized. For example, +1 (555) 555-5555 will become 15555555555 after normalization.